# make loop read clearer

Tags: bash, shell, loops, unix

within my while loop I am doing a test, but it seems really redundant and I think there may be a better solution to implement this such as a "case" structure possibly? If anyone can recommend how to cut down on the redundancy that would be wonderful, thanks! Basically, how can I restructure this loop to be better?

the loop:

```
 if [ "$cursor" -eq "1" ]
    then    
        Links="Links: $(ls -ld / | cut -d" " -f2)"
        Owner="Owner: $(ls -ld / | cut -d" " -f3)"
        Group="Group: $(ls -ld / | cut -d" " -f4)"
        Size="Size: $(ls -ld / | cut -d" " -f5)"
        Modified="Modified: $(ls -ld / | cut -d" " -f6-8)"
        echo "$Links  $Owner  $Group  $Size  $Modified" 
    elif [ "$cursor" -eq "2" ]
    then    
        Links="Links: $(ls -ld /home | cut -d" " -f2)"
                    Owner="Owner: $(ls -ld /home | cut -d" " -f3)"
                    Group="Group: $(ls -ld /home | cut -d" " -f4)"
                    Size="Size: $(ls -ld /home | cut -d" " -f5)"
                    Modified="Modified: $(ls -ld /home | cut -d" " -f6-8)"
                    echo "$Links  $Owner  $Group  $Size  $Modified"
        elif [ "$cursor" -eq "3" ]
    then
        Links="Links: $(ls -ld ~ | cut -d" " -f2)"
                    Owner="Owner: $(ls -ld ~ | cut -d" " -f3)"
                    Group="Group: $(ls -ld ~ | cut -d" " -f4)"
                    Size="Size: $(ls -ld ~ | cut -d" " -f5)"
                    Modified="Modified: $(ls -ld ~ | cut -d" " -f6-8)"
                    echo "$Links  $Owner  $Group  $Size  $Modified"         
    else
        temp=`expr $cursor - 1` 
        curDir=${currentdir[$temp]}
        Links="Links: $(ls -ld $curDir | cut -d" " -f2)"
                    Owner="Owner: $(ls -ld $curDir | cut -d" " -f3)"
                    Group="Group: $(ls -ld $curDir | cut -d" " -f4)"
                    Size="Size: $(ls -ld $curDir | cut -d" " -f5)"
                    Modified="Modified: $(ls -ld $curDir | cut -d" " -f6-8)"
                    echo "$Links  $Owner  $Group  $Size  $Modified"  
fi
```

Comment: You **really** shouldn't be parsing the output of `ls`. See [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: (and even if you *were* going to do so, it'd be much more sensible to run `ls` *once* and read that single invocation's output into five fields, rather than running it five separate times and extracting one field each).

Comment: If you have GNU stat, you could literally craft a single `stat -c` invocation that emits your link, owner, group, size and mtime output all in a single command.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that no problem. When approaching this problem think about what piece of information is changing in your statements, use a variable to store this information. In the end try to reduce repeated lines by using functions, variables, and ordering.

Move the following block out of your if/else statements. Within each if statement, set the variable curDir="[dir]"

```
 Links="Links: $(ls -ld $curDir | cut -d" " -f2)"
 Owner="Owner: $(ls -ld $curDir | cut -d" " -f3)"
 Group="Group: $(ls -ld $curDir | cut -d" " -f4)"
 Size="Size: $(ls -ld $curdir | cut -d" " -f5)"
 Modified="Modified: $(ls -ld $curdir | cut -d" " -f6-8)"
 echo "$Links  $Owner  $Group  $Size  $Modified"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cursor="$1"
case "$cursor" in
    1) curDir="/"
    ;;
    2) curDir="/home"
    ;;
    3) curDir="${HOME}"
    ;;
    *) curDir=${currentdir[$temp]}
    ;;
esac

Links="Links: $(ls -ld $curDir | cut -d" " -f2)"
Owner="Owner: $(ls -ld $curDir | cut -d" " -f3)"
Group="Group: $(ls -ld $curDir | cut -d" " -f4)"
Size="Size: $(ls -ld $curDir | cut -d" " -f5)"
Modified="Modified: $(ls -ld $curDir | cut -d" " -f6-8)"
echo "$Links  $Owner  $Group  $Size  $Modified"
```

Answer (score 0):

I concur, scraping `ls` is not the best, but I'm not sure what your use-case is. Here's a solution I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_stat()
{
  path="$1"

  IFS=":" read links owner group size modified <<<$(ls -ld $path | awk '{print $2":"$3":"$4":"$5":"$6" "$7" "$8}')
  echo "$links $owner $group $size $modified"
}

case $cursor in
  1) my_stat /;;
  2) my_stat /home;;
  3) my_stat ~;;
  *) temp=$((cursor - 1))
     curDir="${currentdir[$temp]}"
     my_stat "$curDir"
  ;;
esac
```

Even this is is probably not the most optimal way to accomplish your goal. One thing that sticks out at me is the `$cursor` variable. That's an enigma to me of what you're trying to accomplish here. At any rate, hopefully, this helps a little.